# How to group together X number of days to get total amount of occurences?

Tags: r

I have a df (due_date) with 1000s of rows in ascending days, each row is a day (as "1 day, 2 days, etc" and is in the time format as "days") since an event occurred, so c1 is each day, and c2 is the number of people on each of those days. Here is a small example of my df:

```
diff_in_days  number_of_people
1 days        100
2 days        50
3 days        200
4 days        20
5 days        25
6 days        500
```

I am trying to figure out a code that I can use to group together a certain number of days and then get the total number of people from that grouping. For example I want to group "1 day through 3 days" and would get the total of 350, and then group days >= 4 and get 545. The new data frame would look like something along:

```
diff_in_days  number_of_people
1:3 days      350
>=4 days      545
```

So far I have tried different combos of group_by such as:

```
due_date %>%
 group_by(diff_in_days == 0:3, >=4)

due_date %>%
  group_by(diff_in_days == "0 days:3 days", ">=4 days")

due_date %>%
 group_by(diff_in_days(==0:3,>=4)
```

If I try grouping multiple days, R gives me "unexpected symbol" after the first 'group':

```
Error: unexpected '==' in:
"due_date %>%
group_by(diff_in_days(=="
```

I've tried with/without quotes, etc. If I put only:

```
due_date %>%
  group_by(diff_in_days == "0 days:3 days")
```

I get a third column with column named as: **diff_in_days == "0 days:3 days"**

And each row in the column is filled with "FALSE". The units used to find the difference in date is "days", but if I get rid of *units = c("days")*, it turns the unit into seconds which I don't want. I have multiple df's of the similar data, but some days might be missing, so the data might look like below, so I wouldn't be able to apply the same specific row numbers across each of them. The grouping specifically has to be based off of the range of days I select for diff_in_day.

```
diff_in_days  number_of_people
3 days        200
4 days        20
6 days        500
```

If I need to clarify anything, please let me know, but I cannot post full code due to sensitivity. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need a simple ifelse. Either create a new variable or replace existing one

Comment: `due_date %>% group_by(diff_in_days = ifelse(diff_in_days > 3, '>=4', '1:3 days')) %>%
  summarise(number_of_people = sum(number_of_people))`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you might use `cut` and provide cutoff points to split up into groups of days. If the column `diff_in_days` is `difftime`, you can add `as.numeric`.

```
library(dplyr)

due_date %>%
  group_by(group = cut(as.numeric(diff_in_days), 
                       breaks = c(1, 3, Inf), 
                       include.lowest = T)) %>%
  summarise(number_of_people = sum(number_of_people))
```

**Output**

```
  group   number_of_people
  <fct>              <int>
1 [1,3]                350
2 (3,Inf]              545
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to write a simple function that would do the formatting and grouping. First, replace strings with numeric values and then aggregate with these values. Something like this:

```
group_by_range = function(data, range) {
  col = data$diff_in_days
  col = gsub(" days", "", col)
  col = as.numeric(col)
  
  col = ifelse(col > max(range), sprintf(">=%s days", max(range) + 1), sprintf("%s:%s days", min(range), max(range)))
  res = aggregate(data$number_of_people, by = list(diff_in_days = col), FUN = sum)
  colnames(res) = colnames(data)
  return(res)
}

d = group_by_range(due_date, 1:3)
```

Output:

```
  diff_in_days number_of_people
1     >=4 days              545
2     1:3 days              350
```

Comment: I tried this and I got this error with the last line:
```
Error in names(x) <- value : 
  'names' attribute [3] must be the same length as the vector [2]
```